# Really switch among all the applications by shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, application-switcher

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.3. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is used to switch among different applications, but sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I guess it is because some applications are hidden or minimized.

Is there a way to **really** switch among all the applications by shortcuts no matter whether they are hidden or minimized?

Answer (score 4):

If you use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to go through your open applications, you should see even minimized ones, but if you select them, they don't automatically maximize/unminize. If you however press the <kbd>option</kbd> key *after* you've selected the desired minimized application but *before releasing* the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, the app window that was minimized to the dock will return to its previous view.

I know this probably isn't exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps it'll help nonetheless.

Following this tip should also create a window for apps with no active window (works for Mail, iTunes and Keynote).

You can also switch from an app to "itself" (by hitting <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> once) then holding option before letting go of command will unminimize or create the window.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the `option` key after I've selected the desired minimized application... but it still does not appear...

Comment: owenfi made some changes to my post to make it clearer, did you see the changes?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try one of the following add ons:

http://manytricks.com/witch/

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8242/liteswitch-x
(company website no longer seems to exist)

Both apps claim to solve the minimized app problem.